# @font-face is unable to find the woff2 file i have in the repository

Tags: css, sass, fonts

I am having an issue importing fonts. Here's how the file i am trying to use to import fonts looks

```
`
@font-face {
    font-family: "Epilogue Regular";
    src: url("../fonts/woff2/Epilogue-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Epilogue Italic";
    src: url("../fonts/woff2/Epilogue-Italic.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Epilogue Bold";
    src: url("../fonts/woff2/Epilogue-Bold.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  `
```

the sructure of the folders is something like this:

```
`>assets
  >fonts
  _fontImports.scss
   >woff2
   Epilogue-Regular.woff2
   Epilogue-Italic.woff2
   Epilogue-Bold.woff2`
```

Aside from that, I imported the @font-face to _styles.scss. the imports inside this file look like this

```
`@use './assets/fonts/_fontImports.scss' as *;
@use './assets/styles/abstract/_abstract.scss' as *;`
```

I am really stumped right now and can't find the answer for this. I appreciate the help! If theres something I forgot to mention I will answer to your questions as quickly as I can

I've tried changing the file location on the src url a lot, trying to work around it so it can find it but no matter what I do it just can't find the font face

Comment: Your font file paths need to be **relative to the final compiled css file**. So where is your final css file eventually stored? Please check your devtools for error logs and the network tab filtered by fonts. If you're using webpack your fonts might be corrupted during the bundling process - in this case you would see a OTS parsing error in your console.